# "ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

Why am i getting " ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at showRoom (:15:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (http://null.jsbin.com/runner:1:1450) " when I try using the function via onclick. The sound part works so the sound plays, but it does not change room and gives me this error.

```
var showRoom = function(room_id) {
    if(room_id == '#start'){
      soundIntro.play();

    }

    else {

      soundHadouken.play();

    }

$('.room').fadeOut();

$(room_id).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    console.log('play music')
}); 

console.log('working');
```

}

Comment: You should really have Googled that error.

Comment: Found the answer to the reference error, sorry. But that solution gave me another reference error. That showRoom isn´t defined.